# Как применить общий класс к колонкам таблиц на странице?

Tags: css3, bootstrap

Есть страничка, на которой с помощью bootstrap-table создано 3-4 таблицы. Каждая таблица имеет 2 колонки. Судя по всему из-за того,что это отдельные таблицы, ширина колонок в каждой разная, мне же нужно сделать 50% на 50%. Как это можно решить?У меня предположение создать класс css для  с width:50%,но как сделать так, чтобы он автоматически применялся ко всем td таблицы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

прописал в .css новый класс:
table.two-col td, table.two-col th с нужной шириной,потом к классу таблицы добавил two-col и все пошло